# AtributeError: module gameutils has no attribute 'ch'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributeerror

So I have this problem with main.py. Then I run main.py, it gives me an attribute error.

gameutils.py:

```
class gameutils:                                         
  def main():                                              
    return True                                                       
  def ch():                                                
    input = ('What will you choose to do next? ')          
    print()                                                
    print('You\'ve chosen to ' + input + '.')              
    return input
```

And main.py:

```
from gameutils import ch

ch()
```

Also, gameutils.py and main.py are in the same directory. What could the problem be? Also I am running it in Python 3 in Termux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the module(.py file) not the class. So please try

`from gameutils import gameutils` 
  This will load gameutils class from gameutils module i.e the .py file

and then

`gameutils.ch() # This is the actual class`